# Printing specific lines of a file

Tags: c

I'm trying to printf specific lines of a .txt file by comparing the first char of the line to "-", and only printing if it isn't the same.

```
void menu() {

  FILE *fp =fopen("save_projeto.txt","r");
  char line[MAX_LENGTH];
  fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, fp);

  while(!feof(fp)){

    if (strcmp(line[0], "-") == 0) {
        fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, fp);
    }

    else {
        printf("%s", line);
        fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH, fp);
    }
  }
}
```

The file I'm trying to print is formatted like this, with 20 Locals and each one with up to 1.3 different PDI's.

```
1º Local
Amsterdao

1.1 PDI
Casa de Anne Frank
-Descricao: Museu biografico localizado na cidade de Amsterdao, capital dos Paises Baixos.
-Horario de funcionamento: *7*19
```

When I build the code, it runs without error messages, but the console does not print anything at all.

Comment: `if (strcmp(line[0], "-") == 0)` ==> `if (line[0] == '-')`

Comment: 1. You need to read the line before you test to see if the first char is '-'. 2. Don't use strcmp, you are not comparing strings you are comparing characters.

Comment: Have replaced the condition with line[0] == '-', but it still won't print any line whatsoever.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong

Comment: Don't read whole lines--you only need one character at a time.  Read the first char.  If it isn't `-`, print it and enter state PRINTING.  If it is, enter state NOTPRINTING.  Read the next character and print or not depending on the current state.  If you read a newline, you may transition states on the next read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't read more than you need to.  One character at a time will do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Print lines that do not start with '-' */
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int first_char=1;
        int print;
        int c;

        FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1],"r") : stdin;
        if( fp == NULL ) {
                perror(argv[1]);
                return 1;
        }

        while( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF ) {
                if( first_char )
                        print = c != '-';
                if( print )
                        putchar(c);
                first_char = c == '\n';
        }
        return ferror(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` compares an entire string, not just a single character out of it.

Write `line[0] == '-'` as a condition for testing just the first character. And note the single quotes in `'-'`, which denote a single character, whereas double quotes like `"-"` represent a 0-terminated string literal.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison should be for the first character:

```
if (line[0] == '-') {
    /* First char is a dash */
}
```

Perhaps add a newline to the string when printing?

```
 printf("%s\n", line);
```

If you want each line to be immediately written to the output stream, then `fflush` it:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Corot Another approach to solving your problem is the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

/* Path to the file you are reading */
#define FILENAME  "save_projeo.txt"

/* Set the maximum length of text line in the input file */
#define MAX_LENGTH    92

/**************
 * Main Driver
 **************/
 int main()
 {
     FILE *fp;
     char buffer[MAX_LENGTH+1]; // buffer to hold data read from input file
     const char *str = "-";  // String (here char) to be searched
     size_t num = 1;

     fp = fopen(FILENAME, "r");

     // Is the file opened to read?
     if( !fp){
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file <%s>\n", FILENAME);
         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
     while(fgets(buffer, MAX_LENGTH, fp)){
          // If the first num bytes of buffer does not match the first num byte of str
          // then print the content of buffer
          if(memcmp(buffer, str, num) != 0)
              printf("%s\n", buffer);
     }
     fclose(fp);
     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
 }
```